# How to write validation for my date and time fields?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Can somebody help me or give me a tip on how to write validation for these two date and time fields, so I am able to save only dates in the format that `datepicker` gives me (11/20/2016) and time the way it is in the value attributes below. Currently I am able to save an empty field (null) for date and "Time" for time and I want to be able to save only in the given formats when the `submit` button is clicked. I have been trying to do this for way too long, but i simply couldn't make it work.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="date">Date:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-2" class="dpckr">
    <!-- <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYY" type="text"/> -->
    <input id="date" type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="date" value="Click to select date" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="text">Hour:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <select class="form-control sct" id="time" name="time">
      <option value="">Time</option>
      <option value="10am">10:00-10:30</option>
      <option value="1030am">10:30-11:00</option>
      <option value="11am">11:00-11:30</option>
      <option value="1130am">11:30-12:00</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="saveAppt" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a regular expression, it is possible to match a numeric pattern such as 99/99/9999 but as you can see there is more to check when validating a date. Months should fall in the range 01-12, days between 01-31 conditioned on the current month (and leap year).

For this date validation part of the problem, I pull in another library, [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). You might be able to get away with using `Date.parse()` vanilla Javascript but Moment is more powerful if you can use it.

Below I provide a `validate` function that does a couple of things: 1) regex match the date format, and 2) if a match is found validate the matched value with the Moment library. If both validations pass, I log true otherwise false. You can play around with the snippet below.

```js
function validate() {
    
    // regex pattern to match MM/DD/YYYY
    var pattern = /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/;
    var date = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
    
    // RegExp.test returns explicit true or false if match is found or not
    var isMatch = pattern.test(date);
    
    // if a match is found, we still need to validate it as a proper date
    if (isMatch) {
        var strict = true; // require strict match, see moment docs
        var format = 'MM/DD/YYYY';
        var isValid = moment(date, format, strict).isValid();
        if (isValid)
            console.log('valid');
        else
            console.log('not valid');
    } else {
        console.log('not valid');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<input id="datepicker" value="01/24/1982">
<button onclick="validate()">Match</button>
```

Comment: You could rewrite validate with a date parameter. You could also overload it with a format parameter, then you would have a validate function for any date in any format. Return true or false instead of using alerts.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I wil play with the code now.